# cin.get() not working as it should

Tags: c++, arrays, cin

Here is my program:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string.h>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
 char leos[30];
 cin.get( leos,30 );
 cout<<leos;
 return 0;
 }
```

I learned that in order to use the cin.get function I must specify the name of the array(leos) and then the number of characters to be read(and optionally a terminating character).However,this program will read only one character,even if the introduced number of characters to be read is 30.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Works for me.](http://ideone.com/ZTuaSq) What are your input and output?

Comment: works for me, too. what did you try to input?

Comment: I tried some letters:t,a,etc

Comment: What *exactly* were the input and output? Including any whitespace there may have been. "Some letters" is not helpful.

Comment: It appears that the OP seems confused about the stream size option of  `cin.get()`and expects it to read as long as he hasn't written 30 characters. However the documentation states that if no delimiter is specified it will read until it encounters a newline or reads n-1 characters (in this case 29)

Comment: The downvotes are because (a) the problem is not well stated, with no testcase provided despite this being mandated in the How To Ask help pages, and (b) the problem is not reproducible (i.e. it does not appear to exist).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I thought that in order to introduce the characters ,I had to press enter after each of them.I must introduce the characters one after another and then press enter in order to finish reading.